# Select all the cells in UITableView

Tags: iphone

what would be the best method  to select all the cells in the table(UITableView) when the user presses a button in the tool bar?

Comment: What's your use case for this?  If you're trying to persist a table row selection, be aware that you will be rejected from the App Store if you do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select a cell calling table view's selectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
[menuTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

However you can't select multiple cells in a UITableView. 
If you want to show and process on/off state of cells you should use cell with accessory view with UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark type. (see docs for more details)

Comment: You can select multiple cells if the table view allowsMultipleSelection.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy, you are right. Unfortunately that functionality was not available in 2009 )

Comment: Remember to set `UITableViewScrollPosition` to `.None`.

Answer (score 29):

Here is my method to traverse a table, it works well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ptableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < [ptableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
        NSUInteger ints[2] = {i,j};
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:ints length:2];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [ptableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
           //Here is your code

    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This can select all rows in the table view:

```
for (NSInteger s = 0; s < self.tableView.numberOfSections; s++) {
        for (NSInteger r = 0; r < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++) {
            [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s]
                                        animated:NO
                                  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried it myself, but try this:

In your button action, loop through the indexPath and call it:

```
for (i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
         indexPath.row = j;
         indexPath.section = i;
         [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:animated scrollPosition:scrollPosition];
    }
}
```

Comment: When you select each new cell - selection from previous removed. You can't get multiple selection in UITableView it seems

Comment: I wonder if you can reject the deselection in the tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method. (Return nil if you don’t want the row deselected.)

Comment: I does not work for either. 
Anyway the main point (imo, but can't find an exact place in HIG) is just that you should not select more then one cell at a time and selection state must not be persistent - you select table cell to do something. You should use cell's checkmark accessory view for changing/showing cell state.

Comment: I guess the solution then is to persist each selection internally (as what you say in your response) and color the cell accordingly to indicate a different type of selection (or use the check mark).