# How to apply checkmarks to all cells in table on click of button on toolbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select all the cells in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524043/select-all-the-cells-in-uitableview)

I have table of 15 rows, when i click a button on toolbar i need to apply the checkmarks on all the 15cells at a time. Can somebody help i need it urgently.....

Comment: This is very close to duplicating your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524043/select-all-the-cells-in-uitableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to my response to one of your past questions:

```
for (i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
         indexPath.row = j;
         indexPath.section = i;
         // set checkmark.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set a check n the data model and then reload the UITableView to display the data along with the checkmark.