# UITableView SelectAll - willDeselectRowAtIndexPath alternative

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uikit

I built a multi-selection table, I did that using willSelectRowAtIndexPath and willDeselectRowAtIndexPath. It is working fine. Now I want to programatically selectALL or Select None. Is there a way to call

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

without having the currently selected row unselected? I read in documentation, this method does not call delegate's willDeselectRowAtIndexPath.

Here's all code to allow multiple selection. The problem is now that I cannot select programmatically without deselecting previous.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSDictionary* friend = [friendsData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
    if (![selectedIndexes containsObject:friend]) {
        [selectedIndexes addObject:friend];

    } 
    else {
        [selectedIndexes removeObject:friend];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}


- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary* friend = [friendsData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
    if (![selectedIndexes containsObject:friend]) {
         return indexPath;
     }
    // do not select so we can have multiple select
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change your data source to reflect the select all or select none, then refresh the rows in question to update them to their new status.

I can't post any specific code because it really depends on how you've set up your multi-selection.

### Edit

It seems that you can select all by setting `selectedIndexes` to `friendsData` and select none by clearing the contents of `selectedIndexes`.

**Select All:**

```
[selectedIndexes setArray: friendsData];
```

**Select None:**

```
[selectedIndexes removeAllObjects];
```

Then you can reload your table view. If you want it to be instant, execute `[tableView reloadData]` otherwise you can use the reload methods with animation.

Comment: selectedIndexes is an array created by me. Just adding to them does not help. Also tried setting cell.selected = true on tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath but I can see it selected at start and then immediately unselected.

Comment: Instead of using the `selected` property of the cells, you should add a checkmark or some other image to the cells.

Comment: Can't use that, but I solved it by adding extending UITableCellView making the default selected setter do nothing and a new selected property 'reallySelected' that sets selected when appropriate. Btw, since your suggestions helped me, I am accepting your answer... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is method to traverse a table, it works well.

[Select all the cells in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524043/select-all-the-cells-in-uitableview)

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ptableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < [ptableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
    NSUInteger ints[2] = {i,j};
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:ints length:2];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [ptableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       //Here is your code

  }
 }
```