# How to insert checkmarks when "Select All" button is clicked in the tool bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am a newbie for iPhone development. Please tell me how to insert checkmarks for all the cells when I click on "select All" button in the tool bar. Right now I am able to select all the images and store it in an Array but not able to insert checkmarks for all the cells. This is how my code looks as of now. Please tell me what are the changes I have to do in my code.

```
-(IBAction) selectAll: (id)sender
{
    [selectedZipImagesList addObjectsFromArray: zipImageslist];
    NSLog(@"All images are: %@",selectedZipImagesList);
    for (int s = 0; s < self.tableView.numberOfSections; s++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:s]; r++)
        {
            [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:r inSection:s] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same method but the checkmarks are not getting inserted.

Comment: You shouldn't check the state of each cell due to the fact that these cells are reuses. What you need is a data source that fits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i check this [sample code](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/checkmark) it working

[image]

after select all button

[image]

Comment: have you check sample code ??

Comment: Ya its a perfect sample code for my project. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Reload the table after adding all values to array,

```
[tableview reloaddata];
```

Comment: Even reloading the table is not working.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7190865/756941) answer, it may help you.